# Python regex to find value in double quotes (ignoring other languages character)

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I want an image url from string which must contain specific string like `J02487`. Below I've mentioned that string. We have multiple urls but i only want that url which must have this string `J02487`.

```
{url:"https:\u002F\u002Fuk.louisvuitton.com\u002Fimages\u002Fis\u002Fimage\u002Flv\u002F1\u002FPP_VP_L\u002Flouis-vuitton-bandoulière-monogram-canvas-wallets-and-small-leather-goods--J02485_PM1_Closeup view.jpg"},{url:"https:\u002F\u002Fuk.louisvuitton.com\u002Fimages\u002Fis\u002Fimage\u002Flv\u002F1\u002FPP_VP_L\u002Flouis-vuitton-bandoulière-monogram-canvas-wallets-and-small-leather-goods--J02485_PM1_Back view.jpg"}],mediaUrl:bA,price:aL,priceRaw:bv,currency:aH,color:"Macadamia",size:a,material:bn,disambiguatingDescription:aG,colorIconURL:"https:\u002F\u002Fuk.louisvuitton.com\u002Fimages\u002Fis\u002Fimage\u002Flv\u002F1\u002FLV\u002Flouis-vuitton--MKC-LG-994_rose_clair.jpg",detailedDescription:"\u003Cul\u003E\n  \u003Cli\u003EMacadamia Pink\u002FWhite \u003C\u002Fli\u003E\n  \u003Cli\u003ENylon and Monogram coated canvas \u003C\u002Fli\u003E\n  \u003Cli\u003ENylon lining \u003C\u002Fli\u003E\n  \u003Cli\u003EGold-colour hardware\u003C\u002Fli\u003E\n\u003Cli\u003EStrap: Non-removable, adjustable\u003C\u002Fli\u003E\u003Cli\u003EStrap Drop: 32.0 cm\u002F12.6 inches\u003C\u002Fli\u003E\u003Cli\u003EStrap Drop Max: 52.0 cm\u002F20.5 inches\u003C\u002Fli\u003E\u003C\u002Ful\u003E",activateEngraving:b,sellable:d,cscSellable:d,mom:b,locateInStore:d,materialGroupCode:bf,backOrderDisclaimer:d,backOrderFullDeposit:b,dimensions:{values:{depth:aX,height:aw,width:aT},valuesAlt:{depth:bN,height:bL,width:bI},unitText:at,unitTextAlt:ar},productId:H},{identifier:"J02487",name:v,url:"\u002Feng-gb\u002Fproducts\u002Fbandouliere-monogram-nvprod2420049v#J02487",medias:[{url:cq},{url:"https:\u002F\u002Fuk.louisvuitton.com\u002Fimages\u002Fis\u002Fimage\u002Flv\u002F1\u002FPP_VP_L\u002Flouis-vuitton-bandoulière-monogram-canvas-wallets-and-small-leather-goods--J02487_PM1_Closeup view.jpg"}
```

The output should be this.

`https:\u002F\u002Fuk.louisvuitton.com\u002Fimages\u002Fis\u002Fimage\u002Flv\u002F1\u002FPP_VP_L\u002Flouis-vuitton-bandoulière-monogram-canvas-wallets-and-small-leather-goods--J02487_PM1_Closeup view.jpg`

I've tried this

`\"(http.*?J02487.*?jpg)\"`

and many other options but didn't find an accurate solution. Anyone who can help? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
"(https?:[^"]*J02487[^"]*\.jpg)"
```

- `"` Match `"`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `https?:` Match http with optional s and `:`
  - `[^"]*J02487[^"]*` Match `J02487` between any chars except `"`
  - `\.jpg` Match `.jpg` and note to escape the dot
- `)"` Close group 1 and match "

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gRqgAG/1)